# Deploy view or use function for lookup

Tags: function, view, performance

I've two master tables **Org** & **Item** and then there's an **OrgItem** table.I have to fetch *ItemCodes* for a particular Org.

TABLE STRUCTURE:

- Org ( Id, OrgCode, Name) - Org Master table
- Item ( Id, ItemCode, Name) - Item Master table
- OrgItem ( ItemId, OrgId, ItemCode) - Some Org specific ItemCodes

---

Now only some Item's have Org specific ItemCode so by default I fetch the ItemCode from Item but if for a particular Item+Org combination **if its record exists** in the OrgItem table then I have to fetch the ItemCode from the OrgItem table.

Creating a **View_OrgItem_Item** might be a solution but it would mean a view which consists of n-fold the size of the original Item table (where n = number of Orgs).

Another option is to create a **GetItemCode(ItemId, OrgId)** which does the lookup and return either Item.ItemCode or ORgITem.ItemCode

So, my question is - should I go for a 'View_OrgItem_Item' or simply create a function 
GetItemCode(ItemId, OrgId)?

Which one is best in terms of performance? Any other factors to consider.

**Note: It is NOT necessary that ALL the Orgs have records in OrgItem*

Comment: What technology is this question about? SQL maybe? Could you add the name of the technology as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost always going to be the case that the view will perform better than using a function.  This is because you will often want to get the item code in a set-based fashion.  With a function, this lookup has to happen under the covers, row by row.  With a view, you can do a simple join and the query optimizer can choose more optimal plans than a row-by-row lookup, which is what the function essentially forces.

Comment: +1: If the function is called in the SELECT (which would be the case here), you're running a SUBSELECT - it's going to execute for every record returned.  You'll get what you want, but the performance will get worse as the number of rows increases.